# ASP.NET MVC - how to return a FileResult, while file is at another site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am writing url redirector. Now I am struggling with this:

Let's say I have this method:

```
public FileResult ImageRedirect(string url)
```

and I pass this string as an input: `http://someurl.com/somedirectory/someimage.someExtension`.

Now, I want my method to download that image from `someurl`, and return it as a `File()`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class to download the file from the remote url and then return it using the `Controller.File` method. [`DownLoadData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method in WebClient class will do the trick for you.

So you can write an action method like this which accepts the fileName(url to the file)

```
public ActionResult GetImage(string fileName)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {                   
            var byteArr= wc.DownloadData(fileName);
            return File(byteArr, "image/png");
        }
    }
    return Content("No file name provided");
}
```

So you can execute this by calling

```
yoursitename/yourController/GetImage?fileName="http://somesite.com/logo.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are **potentially allowing** user to make your server to download any file on the web, I think you WANT to limit the maximum download file size.

To do so, you can use this code :

```
public static MemoryStream downloadFile(string url, Int64 fileMaxKbSize = 1024)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        webRequest.Method = "GET";

        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        Int64 fileSize = webResponse.ContentLength;
        if (fileSize < fileMaxKbSize * 1024)
        {
            // Download the file
            Stream receiveStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = receiveStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0 && bytesRead <= fileMaxKbSize * 1024)
            {
                m.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            // Or using statement instead
            m.Position = 0;

            webResponse.Close();
            return m;
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // proper handling
    }

    return null;
}
```

And in your case, to be use like this :

```
public ActionResult GetImage(string fileName)
{

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
    {
        return File(downloadFile(fileName, 2048), "image/png");
    }
    return Content("No file name provided");
}
```

*fileMaxKbSize* represents the maximum size allowed in kb (default is 1Mb)